# Is this database model less efficient?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, performance

I have a problem that implements clients directions, and order directions, both of the directions have the same attributes, so I decided to create a table called Directions, then I created a relation between Clients and Directions and another relation between Orders and Directions.

My question is: it is more efficient to modify both my orders and clients table to manage the directions attributes by their own instead of creating a directions table.

Heres an example of my diagram

[image: Example]

Here is one of my queries:

```sql
SELECT clients.name, work_order.date, direction.street,
direction.city, direction.zip FROM work_orders as work_order
INNER JOIN clients.clients as clients ON client.id = work_order.id_client
INNER JOIN directions.directions as direction ON direction.id = work_order.id_work_direction 
WHERE work_order.id = '1';
```

Comment: One would have to know your queries to answer that.

Comment: Also please only tag the DBMS this is implemented on. Right now you've tagged both mySQL and postgresql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This organization for addresses is likely to be better than the alternative of embedding the address in the separate client and orders tables.  However, there are some issues to consider.

- If you need to update the directions for a client, you need to check whether there are any other clients or orders using the same direction ID.  If there are any shared entries, you'll need to know what to do — is it legitimate to update the direction for them all, or do you need to create a new direction for this client to hold the altered details.
- Do the details for an order need to be frozen, so that if a client places a first order while living in Hawaii, and you complete that order, and then same client moves to Maine and places another order with a new directions, the information for the original order isn't changed?
- In general, countries outside North America do not use the address structure you show.  This may be fine, but is a bigger problem if you need to deal with European or Asian addresses too.
- How will you ensure that you don't have different direction IDs identifying the same address?  Or does that not matter?

Comment: Thank you. For the first issue I'll go with the second option, to create a new address, for the second the data of the order in Hawaii will remain the same , this work is for Mexico here we have the same structure, I see the problem in the fourth issue though I need to rethink my design, but I think I'll keep the addresses in a separate table. Thank you again.